# Handling 'Sequence has no elements' exception dup

Tags: sql

I just finished my ASP.NET hospital management app, everything works fine, but if I try to add a doctor I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException  HResult=0x80131509
> Message=Sequence contains no elements
> Source=Hospital Management System
>
> StackTrace:
>
> at Hospital_Management_System.Controllers.DoctorController.Index(String message) in C:\Users\mouha\OneDrive\Bureau\Hospital Management System\Hospital Management System\Controllers\DoctorController.cs:line 37
> at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
> at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
> at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
> at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
> at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
> at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()

The code:

```
public ActionResult Index(string message)
{
    var date = DateTime.Now.Date;
    ViewBag.Messege = message;

    var user = User.Identity.GetUserId();

    // The exception is being thrown here
    var doctor = db.Doctors.Single(c => c.ApplicationUserId == user); 
    var model = new CollectionOfAll
                    {
                        Ambulances = db.Ambulances.ToList(),
                        Departments = db.Department.ToList(),
                        Doctors = db.Doctors.ToList(),
                        Patients = db.Patients.ToList(),
                        Medicines = db.Medicines.ToList(),
                        ActiveAppointments = db.Appointments.Where(c => c.DoctorId == doctor.Id).Where(c => c.Status).Where(c => c.AppointmentDate >= date).ToList(),
                        PendingAppointments = db.Appointments.Where(c => c.DoctorId == doctor.Id).Where(c => c.Status == false).Where(c => c.AppointmentDate >= date).ToList(),
                        AmbulanceDrivers = db.AmbulanceDrivers.ToList(),
                        Announcements = db.Announcements.Where(c => c.AnnouncementFor == "Doctor").ToList()
                    };

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Without the code this is impossible to debug, please show us the code for the class where the exception is being thrown.

Comment: **Most likely**, there is no `Doctor` with the `user` value that you're getting from `.GetUserId()`. Debug your code - check what you're getting from `GetUserId`, make sure that value is present in the `Doctors` table. I'd also recommend using `SingleOrDefault()` so that if no doctor exists, a `null` is returned (instead of an exception being thrown); you then need to **check for NULL** after the `.SingleOrDefault()` call and abort gracefully if `null` was returned

Comment: There's no SQL at all above. Consider another tag.